# How can i set different hover properties from different elememtns in an HTML page?

Tags: html, css, colors, hover

I have created two divs  (topNavLinks & bottomNavLinks) and both divs contain some links. The hover property for every link on the page is set to black. I want to know how can I set different hover colors for the two divs?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Home</title>
<style>
body {
font-family:"Myriad Pro";
}

#topNavLinks {
background-color:#D5D5D5;
color:#1F8F3C;
font-size:20px;
padding:20px;
margin-bottom:20px;
}

#bottomNavLinks {
background-color:#2B88B5;
color:#FFFFFF;
padding:20px;
}

a:link, a:visited {
color:inherit;
padding:inherit;
text-decoration:none;
}

a:hover, a:active {
color:#0E0E0E;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="topNavLinks">
    <a href="#">Link1</a>
    <a href="#">Link2</a>
    <a href="#">Link3</a>
</div>

<div id="bottomNavLinks">
    <a href="#">Link1</a>
    <a href="#">Link2</a>
    <a href="#">Link3</a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: #topNavLinks a:hover and #bottomNavLinks a:hover will work, just place this after the default one or set your color or property adding !important; after each properties, but i'd place the classes after the default one if i was in you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this

```
  #topNavLinks a:hover{/*do something*/}
  #bottomNavLinks a:hover{/*do something*/}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#topNavLinks a:hover{
}

#bottomNavLinks a:hover{
}
```